# Should I use setInterval() in a watcher?

Tags: vue.js

I'm changing a React app that animates a binary tree to Vue. The vertex and edge components are conditionally rendered based on the value of a `time` prop. The react app works by using the `useInterval` hook to place a delay between rendering each vertex.

React:

```
useInterval(
() => {
  if (time >= maxTimes) setIsUpdating(false)
  setTime((time) => (animate ? Math.min(time + 1, maxTimes) : maxTimes))
},
isUpdating ? DELAY_IN_MS : null
)
```

In order to implement in Vue, I figured I could watch for changes to the value of `time` and call a `setInterval` that incremements `time` some `DELAY_IN_MS` later:

Vue:

```
watch: {
time() {
  setInterval(
    () => {
      if (this.time >= this.maxTimes) {
        this.isUpdating = false;
      }
      this.time = this.animate
        ? Math.min(this.time + 1, this.maxTimes)
        : this.maxTimes;
    },
    this.isUpdating ? DELAY_IN_MS : null
  );
},
},
```

This results in very fast rendering/animation of components, however, and changing `DELAY_IN_MS` doesn't achieve intended results.

Should I use `setInterval` somewhere other than in a watcher?

I realize assigning a new value to `time` in it's watcher might be recursive and problematic. Is that the problem?

Comment: It's unknown how it originally worked in React and so how it should in Vue. It runs recursively because you never check if `time` value has changed in a watcher. Doing this in a watcher is most likely a mistake because you create a lot of intervals and never clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that this inside of the setInterval 'this' doesn't reference anymore to vue instance.

To solve this problem I'd try something like creating a const to hold the 'this' that references to vue instance.

The code could be like this!

```
watch: {
time() {
  const vueThis = this;
  setInterval(
    () => {
      if (vueThis.time >= vueThis.maxTimes) {
        vueThis.isUpdating = false;
      }
      vueThis.time = vueThis.animate
        ? Math.min(vueThis.time + 1, vueThis.maxTimes)
        : vueThis.maxTimes;
    },
    vueThis.isUpdating ? DELAY_IN_MS : null
  );
},
```

},

I hope that it can help you!!

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: This is an arrow. `const vueThis = this` isn't needed since ES6.